# Mysql Order By Problematic

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Okay, I'm having some difficulties with order by. Here is the problem I need to solve:

In the database I have written every tile of a map, that is 101 x 101 big. The table has 3 columns(ID, x, y), now I gotta select all the tiles in some radious. For example, I used this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tile 
WHERE ((x >= -3 AND x <= 3) 
AND (y >= -3 AND y <= 3)) 
ORDER BY x ASC, y DESC;
```

This query selects all tiles in radius of 3 of the given coordinate (0|0) for now.

But, it doesn't sort them the way I want it to. Basically, the output must be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTlnp.png).

But this is the closest I got.
http://prntscr.com/zqjd7

**Edit**:
Disregard the double values, had double inputs for each coordinate. Haven't seen it.

Comment: Try `ORDER BY x DESC, y ASC`

Comment: Nope, same, just the x and y are switched.

Comment: My other question/wonder is that you show 7 rows in one row. You are doing some manipulation in your (PHP) application which we know nothing about. The query should result in 49 rows.

Comment: Yes, the query result is 49 rows. I have to sort the rows so they fit perfectly into the prepared table. Every row gets its own cell in the table, i start parsing at the beginning, (-3|3) and end at (3, -3). So the results array must be in the exact order (1 row x go down, y is 3, 2 row x go down, y is 2) and has to go on. So basicly the first 7 results must be formed like this (-3|3, -2|3, -1|3, 0|3, 1|3, 2|3, 3|3).

Comment: Then maybe `ORDER BY y DESC, x ASC`

Comment: Yes this one works, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your problem is around the ASC / DESC modificator.
But since we're here, wouldn't you prefer to use a distance formula? Something near

```
SELECT x, y FROM tile WHERE
(
  POW(x-@var1, 2) + POW(y-@var2, 2) <= POW(3, 2)
)
ORDER BY x DESC, y ASC;
```

Here, given a point P (m,n), we shall know the distance to a fixed point Q (x,y) by acerting `D(P,Q) = SQRT( (x-m)² + (y-n)² )`. As much as it has to be less than (or equals) your desired radius (= 3), we have so `SQRT( (x-m)² + (y-n)² ) <= 3`, or better, `(x-m)² + (y-n)² <= 3²`, raising both terms to its square power.

SQL-language speaking, we write `POW(x-m, 2) + POW(y-n, 2) <= POW(3, 2)`, willing to say that the distance between `(x,y)` and `(m,n)` is last than or equal `3`.

About `@var`, it's where you enter your input value. More specifically, they are session variables, but you don't really want to use it to perform a select; just substitute them by any number you want, e.g. you can choose the origin `(0,0)` by putting `0` on place of `@var1` and `@var2`.

**[Update]**
Well... It's always a good idea to test your code before answering. In fact I should have suggested to order firstly by `y`, since we first care about ordering rows to display on screen. The following code was (finally) tested *(on `test` DB)*; my last suggest is to create the following index (index_y_x):

```
USE `test` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`.`tile` (
  `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `x` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  `y` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT 0 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `index_y_x` (`y` DESC, `x` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

INSERT tile (x,y) VALUES
(-2,-2),(-2, -1),(-2, 0),(-2, 1),(-2, 2),
(-1,-2),(-1, -1),(-1, 0),(-1, 1),(-1, 2),
(0,-2), (0, -1), (0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2),
(1,-2), (1, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2),
(2,-2), (2, -1), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2);

SELECT x, y FROM tile
WHERE POW(x-3, 2) + POW(y-3, 2) <= POW(3, 2)
ORDER BY y DESC, x ASC;
```

*This returns items near the point (3,3), in a range of 3 units*

Comment: Care to explain the @var1 and @var2?

Comment: The OP seems to be using a different distance, not Euclidean.

Comment: I edited my answer. Did I manage to explain it, @n00b?
It will work fine also for integer values. The difference is that the result will be a circle approach, which can be formatted displaying every row according to `y` value, and then centering each line displayed.  
*(Forgive my english, btw)*

Comment: Yes, now i understand it, but still it didn't work. This "ORDER BY y DESC, x ASC" did the trick.

Comment: It doesen't count the negative values... I also added a little bigger map: INSERT tile (x, y) VALUES (-3, -3), (-3, -2), (-3, -1), (-3, 0), (-3, 1), (-3, 2), (-3, 3), (3, -3), (3, -2), (3, -1), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3); POW doesen't always return negative values. Accepted this answer for your effort.

Comment: Ah, maybe it's because I chose the center (3,3) to demonstrate the code, but try out `WHERE POW(x-(-2), 2) + POW(y-(-1), 2) <= ...` - this other example would consider a center (-2, -1). Basically you'll provide the center as input data.

Comment: Geometrically explaining, check out this [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x-%28-2%29%29%5E2%2B%28y-%28-1%29%29%5E2%3C%3D3%5E2)